# Get list of unique ids with consecutive numbers in a column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not sure if it's possible to accomplish this with mysql query alone, but I have a table in the following format:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------+
| id | recipe_id |  ingredient_id  | order |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 1  |     1     |       26        |   2   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 2  |     1     |       95        |   1   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 3  |     1     |       42        |   3   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 4  |     2     |       22        |   1   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 5  |     2     |       15        |   2   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 6  |     2     |       1         |   3   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 7  |     3     |       95        |   1   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 8  |     3     |       33        |   2   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
| 9  |     3     |       23        |   3   |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------|
```

I wanted to generate a list of all `recipe_id` that have a consecutive `order` numbers. ex: 1, 2, 3, and so on, (recipe_id 2 for example) but if the they're not, for example, recipe_id 1 has 2, 1, 3, so it's not in order.

I'm using php, but I wanted to know if this was possible with mysql alone first.

Comment: Try this query `SELECT * FROM some_table a WHERE a.order = ((SELECT b.order FROM some_table b WHERE b.id = (a.id -1)) + 1) ORDER BY a.id DESC GROUP BY a.recipe_id`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible in MySQL alone

Comment: SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY recipe_id ASC, order  ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get all recipes where the order numbers not increasing with the id

```
SELECT * FROM mytable AS a, mytable AS b 
WHERE ((a.id < b.id AND a.order > b.order) OR (a.id > b.id AND a.order < b.order)) AND a.recipe_id = b.recipe_id
```

And this one to get all recipes with there orders as one row

```
SELECT recipe_id, MAX(`order`)-MIN(`order`)+1=COUNT(`order`), GROUP_CONCAT(`order`) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY recipe_id
```

Its only a beginning but i hope it will help you

I create a fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dakAHH5YXt3o1rahXFznLy/0